# Conditional has_many relation in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, has-many, relation

i'm getting data from a third party with own unique keys.

Level1, data_provider_id
Level2, level_1_id, data_provider_id
Level3,level_2_id, data_provider_id

Relations for level1.rb

```
  has_many :level2s, :primary_key => :data_provider_id 
  has_many :level3s, :through => :level2s
```

Relations for level2.rb

```
 has_many :level3s, :primary_key => :data_provider_id
```

If I want to create own Levels i will have to assign a data_provider_id for the relations to work. I could take negative numbers or a range i know the 3rd party will never use but i don't like that approach. Is there a way to make the relation work like the default way when the data_provider_id is nil ?

I tried:

```
  has_many :level2s, :primary_key => (:data_provider_id == nil ? :id : :data_provider_id)
```

But that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using `:data_provider_id is nil ...` instead of `==`? Better yet, just try `:data_provider_id.nil?`, that does the same thing.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your reply. I tried all variations. `("data_provider_id IS NULL" ? :id : :data_provider_id)`. Now all tests pass but it always uses the id eventhough data_provider_id isn't nil. Any ideas?

Comment: Just want to make sure, but did you try putting it in Ruby as well? `:data_provider_id.nil? ? :id : :data_provider_id` is actually a line of Ruby code. I'm not sure if you can throw in SQL in the middle of it like that. Maybe you can.

Comment: I tried that. But then the test which relate on the Levels without data_provider_id fail. No value is assigned to `level2.level1_id` when data_provider_id is nil in the parent level.